# The Report Viewer Web Control HTTP Handler not registered in the application's web.config file

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, reportviewer, reportviewerformvc

The Error:

> The Report Viewer Web Control HTTP Handler has not been registered
>   in the application's web.config file.
>       Add 
>        
>       to the system.web/httpHandlers section of the web.config file, or add 
>        
>       to the system.webServer/handlers section for Internet Information Services 7 or later.

The Web config file :

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
   <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
   <handlers>
    <remove name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler"/>
      <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

The config entries do exists, but the error is still thrown.

Answer (score -1):

Just add this code in web.config
You should ensure your version of Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms (Version=12.0.0.0)

find this section

> *system.webServer*
> *validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" /*    *handlers*
> *add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*"
> path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd"
> type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler,
> Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" /*
> */handlers*
> */system.webServer*
>
> *system.web*
> *compilation debug="true"*
> *assemblies*
> *add assembly="Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" /*
> *add assembly="System.Management, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" /*
> *add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" /*
> *add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" /*
> *add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" /*
> *add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" /*
> *add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" /*
> *add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" /*
> */assemblies*